# WPF DisplayMemberBinding on MultiBinding columns

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I have a `ListView`, and I want to be able to sort any column of it, using `CollectionView`.

When I have a simple binding I meet no problem to set the `PropertyName` of my `SortDescription` :

```
header = ((System.Windows.Data.Binding)headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding).Path.Path;
```

But when I have a MultiBinding, is there a way to take the Path of the first or second binding path?

My XAML is made so :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Quantite}" Width="50">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource :displayQteSurQteTot}">
                            <Binding Path="Quantite" />
                            <Binding Path="TotalQuantity" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I have a `MultiBinding`, is there a way to take the `Path` of the first or second binding path?

Not from the `GridViewColumnHeader` nor the `GridViewColumn` since the `MultiBinding` is only applied to the `TextBlock` element in the `CellTemplate`.

But you could create an attached property and set the path for each column explicitly:

```
public class GridViewColumnExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Path",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(GridViewColumnExtensions),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public static void SetPath(GridViewColumn element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(PathProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetPath(GridViewColumn element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(PathProperty);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Quantite}" Width="50" local:GridViewColumnExtensions.Path="test">
```

**Usage:**

```
string header = GridViewColumnExtensions.GetPath(headerClicked.Column);
```